# Juego mecanografía, verificar palabra introducida

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, viewmodel

Aun soy novatillo en esto, espero puedan echarme un cable. Ando realizando un juego de mecanografía, en la ui te muestra una frase y tu tienes que escribirla correctamente dentro del tiempo. Mi problema viene a la hora de realizar la comprobación de si las palabras introducidas son correctas, ya que tengo que realizar multiples comprobaciones, letra por letra, espacios, mostrar errores etc Mi idea es verificar que cada letra introducida corresponda a la que toque en la frase, y en caso contrario mostrar un error en la pantalla que debe persistir hasta que se corrija el error. Tengo una aproximación pero no es del todo valida aun. Os la dejo por aquí a ver si me podeis ayudar. Gracias!!

**Editado:
Vale, ya he solucionado la mayor parte de los problemas en la verificacion de la palabra. Me quedaría resaltar en rojo la palabra de la frase que debe introducir el usuario. Hay alguna manera de cambiar el color, subrayar o resaltar de algun modo una palabra de un string?? osea imaginad que la frase es "Hola pepe" se podria resaltar de alguna manera "hola" solamente?? Gracias de antemano!!

```
  public void evaluarPalabra()
        {
            palabrasFrase = fraseActual.Split(" "); //Dividir la frase en un array de palabras
            double movimiento = 1000 / palabrasFrase.Length; //Movimiento del camello
            int i = 0;

            if (palabrasFrase.Length > 0) //TODO if, comprobar se escribieron todas las palabras
            {
                //char[] letras = fraseActual.ToArray(); //Separamos la palabra de la frase en caracteres
                char[] letras = palabrasFrase[i].ToArray();
                char[] letras2 = palabraIntroducida.ToArray(); //Separamos la palabra introducida en caracteres

                for (int j = 0; j <= letras2.Length; j++) //Recorremos el array de caracteres de la palabra, y lo comparamos con el array de caracteres de la palabra introducida
                {
                    if (letras[j] != letras2[j]) //Si las letras son distintas
                    {
                        error = "ERROR. ESCRIBE LA PALABRA CORRECTAMENTE"; //Marcamos los errores
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("Error");
                        resaltarPalabraErronea = "Red";
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("ResaltarPalabraErronea");
                    }
                    else if (letras[j] == letras2[j])
                    {
                        error = ""; //Desmarcamos los errores
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("Error");
                        resaltarPalabraErronea = "Black";
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("ResaltarPalabraErronea");
                        moverCamello += movimiento; //La idea es dividir la longitud del canvas en tantas palabras contenga la frase, e ir sumandole la longitud con cada acierto.
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("MoverCamello");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mensajeFinPartida();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: Buenas! no me salta error como tal, pero me falta controlar el tema de los espacios por ejemplo, y que el error mostrado en la UI se quede hasta que el usuario corrija dicho error (de momento salta el error, pero si la siguiente letra introducida es correcta se borra). Como referencia he usado el juego "velocidactil" por si os sirve para ver mejor la idea. Gracias!

Comment: Vale, ya he solucionado la mayor parte de los problemas en la verificacion de la palabra. Me quedaría resaltar en rojo la palabra de la frase que debe introducir el usuario. Hay alguna manera de cambiar el color, subrayar o resaltar de algun modo una palabra de un string?? osea imaginad que la frase es "Hola pepe" se podria resaltar de alguna manera "hola" solamente?? Gracias de antemano!!